# XML blank attribute creation, issue with ':' character

Tags: c#, xml, creation

I am trying to create an xml with the following code.

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

XmlProcessingInstruction xPI = xmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
xmlDocument.AppendChild(xPI);

XmlElement xElmntheader = xmlDocument.CreateElement("soapenv:Header", " ");
xmlDocument.AppendChild(xElmntheader);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
xmlDocument.Save(ms);

string text = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
```

Output is

```
<xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv=" " />
```

I was trying to create like this

```
<xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Header/>
```

How do I eliminate `xmlns:soapenv=" "` from `soapenv:Header`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate that attribute? It's required since you're using an XML namespace called `soapenv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking how to do is create ill-formed (syntactically incorrect) XML. The XmlDocument API is not designed to do that.

If you use the element name

```
soapenv:Header
```

that means `soapenv` is a namespace prefix, which has been declared on this element (or an ancestor) using the `xmlns:soapenv` pseudoattribute. If it has not been declared, your XML output will not be accepted by any self-respecting XML parser.

The method signature you called,

```
xmlDocument.CreateElement(string1, string2);
```

takes two arguments: the qualified name of the element (which may include a prefix, as it does in your case); and a namespace URI. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335911%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) shows what the expected output is:

> The following C# code
>
> ```
> XmlElement elem;
> elem = doc.CreateElement("xy:item", "urn:abc");
> ```
>
> results in an element that is equivalent to the following XML text.
>
> ```
> <xy:item xmlns:item="urn:abc"/>
> ```

The expected namespace URI for this element is "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/". So you will want to declare the soapenv prefix with that namespace URI:

```
string soapNSURI = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
```

and use it thus:

```
XmlElement xElmntheader = xmlDocument.CreateElement("soapenv:Header", soapNSURI);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I added the URI, it worked for me. I was try to do one more insert.                                XmlElement xElmntinsert = xmlDocument.CreateElement("pip:insert", " ");
                xElmntbody.AppendChild(xElmntinsert);                Can I get the namespace for pip also? Once again, thanks for the support.

Comment: @JinoJose: I don't know what namespace "pip" represents. Where did you hear about `pip:insert`?

Comment: pip means Predefind Integration Point and that was a custom Namespace URI. I got the vallue. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Create without the namespace (e.g. use default namespace) and then that part won't be necessary:

```
xmlDocument.CreateElement("Header");
```